# How to put background window/process on top

Tags: c#, user32

I want to create a software like a virtualkeyboard, you have a AlwaysTop Window and use this to put some data on another process/windows. In this case I will record all data on clipboard and compare if this data is compatible with a pattern (`A###` is the patern and `A123` is compatible with the patern), if yes the application will put it in a listbox and the user can paste it on another process/windows (already open) clicking on item on list.

My question is about how to put this information on the last application/process used, I already started a prototype of code but the line indicated is wrong, on my code it's the currentprocess and need to be the last used before click on my form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();   //this line is wrong
    IntPtr hWnd = currentProcess.MainWindowHandle;          //this line is wrong
    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        ShowWindow(hWnd, 9);
    SendKeys.Send("A123");
    }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get on simple solution, instead of get the process I just send the combination ALT+TAB and work for all cases that I need. Below the solution if anyone need in the future:

```
string old_clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
Clipboard.SetText("A123");
SendKeys.SendWait("%{Tab}");
SendKeys.SendWait("^V");
Thread.Sleep(100);
Clipboard.SetText(old_clipboard);
```

Ps.: I put one delay because the SendWait works only on caller windows, as the target of ^V is another process it´s don´t work well.

Best regards. =)